# Need help w/ boolean in room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Before upgrading my AndroidStudio from 4.2 Canary 16 to 4.2 beta 1, I can work easily with boolean in room db using SafeArgs, but now it is not working, boolean cannot set to true. Sample codes are below:
TodoEntity.kt

```
@Entity(tableName = "workout_tb")
data class ElnEntity (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val taskName: String,
    var isDone: Boolean = false
) : Parcelable
```

Fragments where SafeArgs is working earlier-
TaskFragment.kt

```
class TaskFragment : Fragment() {
    ...//some images and text layout codes
        /** finish clicks with boolean *//*
        val done: MenuItem = detailsToolbar.menu.findItem(R.id.act_done)
        val finishIt: CheckBox = done.actionView as CheckBox

        finishIt.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, b ->
            args.getTask.isDone = b             //used to work earlier
            return@setOnCheckedChangeListener
        }
        finishIt.isChecked = args.getTask.isDone

    }
```

I am on latest SafeArgs plugins version. Things I've tried so far:

1. Clean Project and Rebuild Project
2. Invalidate caches

Any help will be great.

Comment: What's the unexpected result? Does it give an error? If so please provide the error message (in your Logcat).

Comment: there is no error, but it won't get boolean to 1 (or true)